# How do I limit the nested queryset in a related serializer to a subset of the related model instances?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have tracks and albums. I would like the ability to mark tracks as deleted but not remove them from the database. I would like tracks that are marked as deleted (is_deleted=True) not to show up in the API in my nested serializer.

I have tried a custom "get_queryset" method on TrackSerializer.py but it is not called.

serializers.py

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
      model = Track

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)
    ### How do I limit tracks in the related/nested serializer to tracks on this album that have not been deleted?
```

models.py

```
class Track(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name="tracks") 

class Album(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
```

Comment: How does your view look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined that I needed to create a custom `ListSerializer` because I have used `many=True`

This is about what I ended up with in `serializers.py`

```
class DeletedListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, data):
        iterable = data.exclude(is_deleted=True) if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
        return [
            self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
        ]


class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
      model = Track

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)
    ### How do I limit tracks in the related/nested serializer to tracks on this album that have not been deleted?

    @classmethod
    def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['child'] = cls()
        return DeletedListSerializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your view looks like. Lets say you are using viewsets. You could overwrite the `def destroy()` function. In which you get the object and change the state of `is_deleted = True`
For example:

```
def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    instance.is_deleted = True
    instance.save()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

For your second problem i recommend writing an explicit filter for django which uses `filters.BaseFilterBackend`

For example:

```
import django_filters
from rest_framework import filters  

class TrackFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):

        def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
            return queryset.filter(is_deleted=False)
```

Then add this to your view as `filter_class = TrackFilterBackend`.

You can find more details on [DJango REST filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#setting-filter-backends)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_tracks(self, album):
        tracks = album.track_set.filter(is_deleted=False)
        return TrackSerializer(tracks, many=True).data
```